# How to compile PicoTCP minimal example on Windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, tcp

I was trying use picoTCP on Windows. I was following the how to compile on Windows from [here](https://github.com/tass-belgium/picotcp/wiki/running-picoTCP-on-windows). This compiled the library successfully with only notes of usleep being deprecated. The next step was to use it.

The example code I wanted to compile was this (main.c):

```
#include <time.h>
#include "pico_stack.h"
#include "pico_ipv4.h"
#include "pico_icmp4.h"

int main() {

    pico_stack_init();
    return 0;
}
```

With a makefile I tried to compile it, which did not work.

```
compile:
    gcc -c -o main.o -Ipicotcp/build/include main.c
    gcc -o main.elf main.o picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a
```

The error message says, that it can't find some random functions

```
C:\Users\______\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv>gcc -o main.elf main.o picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_stack.o): in function `pico_rand':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/stack/pico_stack.c:61: undefined reference to `pico_rand_feed'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_stack.o): in function `pico_stack_recv_new_frame':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/stack/pico_stack.c:453: undefined reference to `pico_rand_feed'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_stack.o): in function `pico_sendto_dev':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/stack/pico_stack.c:539: undefined reference to `pico_rand_feed'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_stack.o): in function `pico_stack_tick':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/stack/pico_stack.c:767: undefined reference to `pico_rand_feed'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/stack/pico_stack.c:770: undefined reference to `pico_rand_feed'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_stack.o):c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/stack/pico_stack.c:773: more undefined references to `pico_rand_feed' follow
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_aodv.o): in function `pico_aodv_init':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/modules/pico_aodv.c:626: undefined reference to `pico_rand'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_dns_client.o): in function `pico_dns_client_query_header':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/modules/pico_dns_client.c:247: undefined reference to `pico_rand'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_igmp.o): in function `srsfst':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/modules/pico_igmp.c:885: undefined reference to `pico_rand'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_igmp.o): in function `mrsrrt':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/modules/pico_igmp.c:927: undefined reference to `pico_rand'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_igmp.o): in function `srst':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/modules/pico_igmp.c:971: undefined reference to `pico_rand'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_igmp.o):c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/modules/pico_igmp.c:1020: more undefined references to `pico_rand' follow
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_device.o): in function `pico_device_ipv6_random_ll':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/stack/pico_device.c:180: undefined reference to `pico_rand_feed'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: picotcp/build/lib/libpicotcp.a(pico_socket.o): in function `pico_socket_high_port':
c:\Users\niklas\repos\fsync\df-sync\modules\protoConv\picotcp/stack/pico_socket.c:808: undefined reference to `pico_rand'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```
The folder structure is as follows
|-main.c
|-Makefile
|-picotcp
```

I downloaded picoTCP from [here](https://github.com/tass-belgium/picotcp/releases/tag/v1.7.0)

From the error messages I can see that it is failing to link the functions, even though they exist but, I could not find a answer on Google for it.
Also this is not a PicoTCP bug, since the example ran on my Linux laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, what caused the missing functions. It is basicly a weak reference to those functions, wich MinGW seems to ignore...
By commenting out the define in pico_config.h like this '#   define WEAK /* **attribute**((weak)) */' I was able to fix the problem.
The github issue can be found [here](https://github.com/tass-belgium/picotcp/issues/523)